# How to use select, max date and declare in a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to use declare and max in variable. This is the query below:

```
Declare @MAX_BUF Datetime
 
Set @OpeningStock = (
                    SELECT @MAX_BUF = MAX(end_date) FROM [IBIS].[buf_stk]
                    WHERE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,end_date ,112 ),1,6)<SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate() ,112 ),1,6);
                    
                    SELECT COUNT(1) AS Opening_Stock 
                    FROM [IBIS].[buf_stk] AS bs(NOLOCK)
                    WHERE CAST(end_date AS DATE)=@MAX_BUF
                    )
```

I am getting syntax error in '=' and '(end_date)'. Please let me know if this can be resolved.

Comment: Your query makes no sense, please explain *in words* what you are trying to do. And properly tag your question; mysql <> sql server

Comment: Your sql is invalid. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: kindly refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=When%20a%20variable%20is%20first,list%20of%20a%20SELECT%20statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this all in one statement and one scan of the table:

```sql
SELECT @MAX_BUF = MAX(end_date), @OpeningStock = COUNT(1)
FROM
    (SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
        CAST(end_date AS date) end_date
    FROM [IBIS].[buf_stk]
    WHERE end_date >= DATEADD(month, 1, getdate())
    ORDER BY CAST(end_date AS date) DESC
    ) t;
```

Notes:

- **Don't use `NOLOCK`, it has many unintended effects and can cause incorrect results**
- Switch round the `WHERE` predicate in order to hit an index if you have one. Don't make the server do algebra for you, it's not very good at it.

Answer (score 1):

Use two statements.  I'm not a fan of converting dates to strings for date arithmetic.  You seem to want the maximum date from before this month.  So, `DATEDIFF()` provides one method (and there are more efficient methods if you have an index on `end_date`):

```
Set @@MAX_BUF = (SELECT CAST(MAX(end_date) as date)
                 FROM [IBIS].[buf_stk]
                 WHERE DATEDIFF(month, end_date, getdate()) >= 1
                );

Set @OpeningStock = (SELECT COUNT(1) AS Opening_Stock 
                     FROM [IBIS].[buf_stk] bs
                     WHERE CAST(end_date AS DATE) = @MAX_BUF
                    );
```

You can also do this as a single statement:

```
select top (1)
       @max_buf = CAST(end_date as date),
       @OpeningStock = COUNT(*)
from FROM [IBIS].[buf_stk] bs
where end_date < dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), convert(date, getdate()))
group by CAST(end_date as date)
order by CAST(end_date as date) desc;
```

Note that this also changes the date comparison to be friendlier to the optimizer.

Comment: Argh how did you manage to copy that second part from my answer while I was still writing it :-) But I like yours better with the `GROUP BY` I didn't think of it that way

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table and data I can't be confident in rewriting your SQL correctly, however all you need to do to "make it work", I suspect, is amend slightly to:

```
SELECT @MAX_BUF = MAX(end_date) FROM [IBIS].[buf_stk]
                    WHERE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,end_date ,112 ),1,6)<SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate() ,112 ),1,6);
                    
                    SELECT @OpeningStock=COUNT(*)
                    FROM [IBIS].[buf_stk] AS bs(NOLOCK) --<< Remove this!
                    WHERE CAST(end_date AS DATE)=@MAX_BUF
```

Having said that, you could combine these into a single query. Your manipulation of dates as strings is *not sargable* and will force the optimizer to scan your table/index.

If you want to find rows where `end_date` is prior to 1st day of the month then just compare as dates (assuming your `end_date` is an actual `date` data type)

`where end_date < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GetDate()), 0)`

And lose the `nolock` hint, unless you prefer your data to be randomly incorrect.